# How do I properly make the images in my divs smaller so they fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to make the most out of this extension http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

And I've managed to implement it into my project but there is a slight issue.

The images I added to the slider doesn't show fully, you can only see the top part of it.

I tried Googling to see if there are other people whos tumbled onto the same issue, I also tried looking at the settings for the extension but itdoesnt seem as if there was anything for changing the sizes, I also tried setting the width and the height of the img inside the div, that made it to what it looks like now.

https://i.imgur.com/ng5qCV1.gifv

The goal is to have them being roughly 100x100px next to each other, being able to see the entire image with a slight margin in between.

```js
$('.caro').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
```

```css
.caro{
    hwidth: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.caro img{
    width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>HMU</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />



</head>

<body>



    <div class="caro">
        <div>
            <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/BeOviHAqNV_jAaNSfjdqR2UB0Jo=/0x0:1600x1067/1200x800/filters:focal(672x406:928x662)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/60427353/11222_Dilling_001.0.jpg" alt="3">
        </div>
        <div>
                <img src="https://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2017/08/clifton-house-project-architecture_dezeen_hero-1.jpg" alt="3">
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is how Slick is supposed to work out of the box. `height: 45px` is what's cutting off the bottom of your images. If you're trying to use this as thumbnails for a larger slideshow, your best option is two use 2 sets of images (one smaller, one larger)

Comment: @Lewis Is there no way to stretch the images so they fit a "frame" let's say I set it to 100x100, isnt there a stretch property or something?

Comment: Because now it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/VBLp7S1.png

Comment: As far as I know, it'll base the width of each indivudal image on the width of the container divided by how many images you tell it to show. Let's say you have 9 images and a 1200px container, but you only tell it to show 3. It will set each image to be 1200/3 wide. If you want finer control, try and set the `slidestoshow` property to a higher number.

Comment: It will only** - You could try setting `slidestoshow` to be 10 and end up with 1200/10 (120px) each.

Answer (score 0):

you can set width and height of Image explicitly (to 100px), but then you won't be able to control slight margin you want. for that, you would need to increase no of Images. and use slick breakpoints.

refer to *responsive* property of slick slider.

See if the code below solves your query,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.caro').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
```

```css
.slick-slide{
  padding:5px;
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>HMU</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" /-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="caro">
    <div>
      <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2017/08/clifton-house-project-architecture_dezeen_hero-1.jpg" alt="3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That just makes the images fullscreen and I can only scroll down, they are not aligned side to side

Answer (score 0):

Mark, try using object-fit for images or background-size for backgrounds.

Object-fit:
https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit/